# First button click to start timer, second to stop

Tags: c#, timer

I'm struggling with making button first click to start a timer, second click to stop the timer and etc.

Can anybody help me? :)

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();
}
```

Comment: Umm.... timer1.Stop()? I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. `Stopwatch` is a better class for timing things by the way.

Comment: That's not enough code to diagnose a problem. Add some more and then tell us exactly what the issue is.

Comment: Ok so I'm trying to make first click to start the timer, but second click on the same button to stop the timer, I dont know if u get it right ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Enabled property:

```
if (timer1.Enabled) {
  timer1.Stop();
} else {
  timer1.Start();
}
```

The Enabled property tells you if the timer is running or not.

Answer (score 6):

One line of code:

```
timer1.Enabled = !timer1.Enabled;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the System.Timers.Timer class, simply use:

```
private void button8_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Stop();
}
```

See the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more handy methods!!

Comment: This will only stop it when he clicks the button. I think he wants to start it if its stopped, or stop it if its started.

Answer (score 0):

When you start a timer, its `Enabled` property is changed to `True`. And when you `Stop` it, it is set back to `False`. So you can use that to check the status of the timer.

```
if (timer1.Enabled)
{
   timer1.Stop();
}
else
{
   timer1.Start();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this !!!!

```
private void button8_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (timer1.Enabled) {
       timer1.Stop();
   } else {
     timer1.Start();
   }
}
```